# Grammaticality of "original italienisches Eis"

Tags: adverb, compound, grammar-identification

Something you will often find is a phrase like:

> original italienisches Eis

What kind of word is *original* here though? An adverb? Shouldn't this phrase be one of the following?

> original-italienisches Eis
>   originales italienisches Eis

You never say the latter and never see the former though. Is this a case of a *very* common “Deppenleerzeichen” or is it me who is the “Depp”?

Comment: Maybe this explains some of the confusion: In English most adverbs are marked by ‑ly while adjectives are not inflected. If an adverb modifying an adjective cannot be recognised as such (e.g., fast), you would use a hyphen to indicate that the adverb modifies the adjective and not the noun. For example *fast-growing group* (schnell wachsende Gruppe) vs. *fast growing group* (schnelle wachsende Gruppe, here the group is fast and growing, but not fast-growing). In German distinction is easy, since adjectives are inflected and thus recognisable as such.

Comment: (Which makes this one of the rare cases, in which the Deppenleerzeichen phenomenon is reversed, i.e., a hyphen is used in English, but a blank is used in German.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function of adverbs is to qualify verbs, adverbs or - as in this example - adjectives. Adverbs do not have any inflexion.
If *original* would be an adjective, describing the noun, only then this word had to be adapted to indicate number, case etc.

That said, *originales Eis* would describe *Eis* as original which, obviously, is not what this sentence intends to convey.

In this particular phrase, *original* specifies *italienisch* to convey that the ice cream is genuinely Italian style.

For that reason, it's correct to say *original italienisches Eis*.

One thing left, what's about *original-italienisches Eis*. Here again, as a compound adjective *original* describes the noun which is not the intended sense.

Comment: "originales Eis would describe Eis as original which, obviously, is not what this sentence intends to convey" - it's actually not that obvious. *original* might refer to the substance, but it could just as well refer to the recipe. Just as *original italienisch* could mean that the ice cream was physically shipped from Italy. Lastly, your claim about *original-italienisch* sounds rather questionable to me.