# Listing adjectives and adverbs qualifying adjectives: should they be declined?

Tags: grammar, adjective, adverb, inflection

**Scroll down for English translation!**

Ich stelle hier mal eine Frage in allgemeiner Form, die hier regelmäßig in verschiedenen Variationen gestellt wird und ich habe auch gleich selbst die richtige Antwort hinzugefügt.

Warum wird das erste Adjektiv in diesen Phrasen nicht gebeugt?

> eine schrecklich nette Familie
>   ein staatlich anerkannter Krankenpfleger
>   ein original italienisches Eis
>   eine schnell wachsende Gruppe
>   ein kurz geschnittener Rasen

Warum sind die folgenden Phrasen falsch?

```
eine schreckliche nette Familie  
ein staatlicher anerkannter Krankenpfleger  
ein originales italienisches Eis  
eine schnelle wachsende Gruppe  
ein kurzer geschnittener Rasen
```

Warum sind die folgenden Phrasen aber trotzdem korrekt?

> ein großer, grüner Ball
>   ein böser, fieser Verbrecher
>   ein dicker, fetter Mann
>   ein langes, dünnes Seil
>   ein kurzer, heftiger Ausbruch

Könnte man nicht auch das schreiben?

```
ein groß grüner Ball  
ein böse fieser Verbrecher  
ein dick fetter Mann  
ein lang dünnes Seil   
ein kurz heftiger Ausbruch
```

---

### Same in English:

I ask here a question in a general way, that is asked here regularly in different variations, and I also did post the correct answer.

Why is the first adjective in this phrases not inflected?

> eine schrecklich nette Familie
>   ...

Why are this phrases wrong?

```
eine schreckliche nette Familie  
...
```

But why are the following phrases still correct?

> ein großer, grüner Ball
>   ...

Can't you write this?

```
ein groß grüner Ball  
...
```

Comment: [Dieser Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6764/grammaticality-of-original-italienisches-eis) sehr sehr ähnlich.

Comment: @c.p. Ja, das stimmt. Ich habe diese Frage formuliert, eben WEIL sie mehreren anderen Fragen sehr ähnlich ist, und die weil Forderung nach einer allgemeinen Behandlung des Themas laut wurde.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe versucht, einen aussagekräftigeren Titel für die Frage zu finden. Wenn der dir nicht gefällt, dann einfach den ursprungligen wiederherstellen.

Comment: @c.p. Ja, der gefällt mir auch. Dieser Titel ist zwar länger, aber man kann ihn trotzdem lassen.

Answer (score 5):

**Scroll down for English translation!**

In „eine schrecklich nette Familie“ ist das erste „Adjektiv“ gar kein Adjektiv, sondern ein Adverb! Das Wort „schrecklich“ bezieht sich nämlich nicht auf das Substantiv „Familie“, sondern auf das Adjektiv „nett“. „Schrecklich“ wird hier verwendet um das Wort „nett“ zu verstärken. Die Familie wird mit dieser Phrase als ganz besonders nett, ja sogar als übertrieben nett beschrieben.

In diesem speziellen Fall (Titel einer Fernsehserie) handelt es sich auch um ein ironisches Wortspiel: Die Familie ist so unglaublich nett, dass man die Familie schon als schrecklich empfindet.

„Schrecklich“ ist in diesem Fall also kein Attribut eines Hauptwortes (das wäre ein Adjektiv), sondern ein Attribut eines Eigenschaftsworts (also ein Adverb).

Adjektive (Attribute von Substantiven) werden gemeinsam mit dem Hauptwort gebeugt, das heißt sie stimmen mit dem Hauptwort, auf das sie sich beziehen, in Kasus, Numerus und Genus überein.

Adverbien (Attribute von Adjektiven und Verben) werden hingegen niemals gebeugt.

---

Die Phrase „eine schreckliche nette Familie“ ist falsch. Es gibt zwei mögliche Korrekturen:

Die erste Möglichkeit: Man streicht man das e am Ende von „schreckliche“ und gelangt so zur oben beschriebenen korrekten Lösung.

Eine andere mögliche Korrektur ist diese:

> eine schreckliche, nette Familie

Hier sind „schreckliche“ und „nette“ zwei Adjektive, die beide dasselbe Hauptwort beschrieben. Die Familie ist sowohl schrecklich als auch nett. Da beide Wörter sich auf dasselbe Wort beziehen, sind sie in eine Aufzählung eingebettet, das heißt, sie müssen entweder durch ein Komma oder durch das Wort „und“ getrennt werden.

---

„Ein großer, grüner Ball“ ist ein anderes Beispiel, das nach dem Muster der oben beschriebenen Korrektur gebildet wird. Die beiden Adjektive „großer“ und „grüner“ beziehen sich beide auf dasselbe Wort, nämlich „Ball“. Sie bilden eine Aufzählung und daher muss ein Komma zwischen ihnen stehen. Auch „ein großer und grüner Ball“ wäre erlaubt und würde dasselbe bedeuten.

---

„Ein groß grüner Ball“ ist falsch, weil „groß“ hier in Gestalt eines ungebeugten Adverbs daherkommt und so tut als wäre es ein Attribut von „grüner“. Das Adjektiv „grün“ kann aber nicht die Eigenschaft „groß“ haben.

Auch „Ein großer grüner Ball“ ist falsch, weil hier das Komma (oder das Wort „und“) fehlt.

---

Übrigens kann man bei einer Aufzählung von Adjektiven die Reihenfolge der Elemente der Aufzählung beliebig ändern, ohne dass dadurch der Sinn verändert wird. Die folgenden vier Phrasen bedeuten alle dasselbe:

> ein großer, grüner Ball
>   ein grüner, großer Ball
>   ein großer und grüner Ball
>   ein grüner und großer Ball

Im anderen Fall (Adverb, Adjektiv, Hauptwort) ist eine Umreihung nicht möglich:

> korrekt: Eine schrecklich nette Familie

```
falsch (1): Eine nette schrecklich Familie  
falsch (2): Eine nett schreckliche Familie  
falsch (3): Eine nette schreckliche Familie
```

ad 1: Das Adverb darf nicht nach dem Adjektiv stehen, auf das es sich bezieht, sondern muss davor stehen.
ad 2: Das Adjektiv „schrecklich“ kann nicht das Attribut „nett“ haben.
ad 3: In der Aufzählung (bestehend aus zwei Adjektiven) fehlt das Komma oder das Wort „und“.

---

### Same in English:

The first “adjective” in “eine schrecklich nette Familie” (“an awfully nice family”) is not an adjective but an adverb! The word “schrecklich” (“awfully” -  NOT “awful”) is not an attribute of the substantive “Familie” (“family”), but of the adjective “nett” (“nice”). “Schrecklich” is used to emphasize the word “nett”. With this phrase the family is described as most particularly nice, even as exaggerated nice.

In this special case (German title of the TV-sitcom “Married... with Children”) the phrase is a word play: The family is so unbelievably nice, that you think it is awful.

In this case “schrecklich” (“awfully” -  NOT “awful”) is not a nouns attribute (this would be an adjective), but an adjectives attribute (i.e. an adverb).

In German language an adjective (a nouns attribute) always has to be inflected, which means, that it must match in grammatical case, number and gender.

An adverb (an attribute of an adjective or a verb) never must be inflected in German language.

---

The term “eine schreckliche nette Familie” is wrong. You have two possibilities to correct it:

First possibility: You delete the e at the end of “schreckliche” which directly leads to the solution described above.

The other possible correction is this:

> eine schreckliche, nette Familie

Here “schrecklich” (“awful” -  NOT “awfully”) and “nett” (“nice”) are two adjectives, that both describe the same noun. The family is both, awful and nice. Since both word refers to the same noun they are embedded in an enumeration. This means, that they must be separated by a comma or by the word “und”.

---

“Ein großer, grüner Ball” is another example that is built after the pattern described above. Both adjectives, “großer” and “grüner” refer to the same word, “Ball”. They form an enumeration, so a comma must be placed between them. Also “ein großer und grüner Ball” would be correct and would mean exactly the same.

---

“Ein groß grüner Ball” is wrong, because “groß” (would be “bigly”, not “big”!) here comes in the shape of an invariant adverb and behaves like an attribute of “grüner”. But the adjective “grün” can not have the property “groß”.

Also wrong is “ein großer grüner Ball” because the comma (or the word “und”) is missing.

---

btw: In an enumeration of adjectives you can change the words sequence arbitrarily without changing the meaning of the phrase. The next four phrases have identical meaning (which is also true for their English translations):

> ein großer, grüner Ball (a big, green ball)
>   ein grüner, großer Ball (a green, big ball)
>   ein großer und grüner Ball (a big and green ball)
>   ein grüner und großer Ball (a green and big ball)

In the other case (adverb, adjective, noun) you can’t change the sequence:

> correct:  Eine schrecklich nette Familie

```
wrong (1): Eine nette schrecklich Familie  
wrong (2): Eine nett schreckliche Familie  
wrong (3): Eine nette schreckliche Familie
```

ad 1: The adverb must not be placed after the referring adjective. It must stand before.
ad 2: The adjective “schrecklich” (“awful”) can’t have the attribute “nett” (“nicely”).
ad 3: In the enumeration (build from two adjectives) the comma or the word “und” is missing.

Comment: Kein Komma zu setzen ist nicht falsch, siehe [Duden-Kommaregel 101](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D101). Die Adjektive sind dann untergeordnet.