# Adjektivierung eines Nomens, das schon mit einem Adjektiv begleitet ist

Tags: adjective

Man betrachte ein von einem Adjektiv begleitetes Nomen, zum Beispiel *mathematische Physik*.

Wie wird dieses Substantiv zu einem Adjektiv? Hier beschränken sich meine Rateversuche auf:

> 1. Sie arbeitet an einem **mathematisch physikalischen** Thema
> 2. Sie arbeitet an einem **mathematischen physikalischen** Thema
> 3. Sie arbeitet an einem **mathematisch-physikalischen** Thema (1. mit Bindestrich)
> 4. Sie arbeitet an einem **mathematischen-physikalischen** Thema (2. mit Bindestrich)

wobei ich die ungeraden Zahlen bevorzuge, also die 2. und 4. für kaum wahrscheinlich halte (aber sie stehen da, weil ich nicht sicher bin; und weil auch kein Komma da ist. Gäbe es ein Komma dazwischen, so würde das "ein Thema" beschreiben, das gleichzeitig genauso *physikalisch* wie *mathematisch* ist, was nicht der Fall ist. Fazit: Ich weiß nicht, ob zwei nicht von keinem Komma getrennte, nacheinander gestellte Adjektive überhaupt grammatisch erlaubt sind).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grammaticality of "original italienisches Eis"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6764/grammaticality-of-original-italienisches-eis)

Comment: If it's a duplicate, please exhibit what's exactly the analogous of *mathematische Physik* in that question. In other words, for this to be a duplicate, *original(-)italienisches* –with or without hyphen– should be the adjectivization of certain already qualified noun. Which one? *"originale Italie"*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Korrekt ist 3.

> Sie arbeitet an einem **mathematisch-physikalischen** Thema (1. mit <del>Bind*en*strich</del> Bind*e*strich)

Eine weitere Möglichkeit ist die Umschreibung mit

> Sie arbeitet an einem Thema **(aus) der mathematischen Physik**.

Der relevante Paragraph des amtlichen Regelwerks ist wohl § 36, insbesondere

> (1) Es wird zusammengeschrieben, wenn […]
>
> - (1.4) es sich um gleichrangige (nebengeordnete) Adjektive handelt […]
>
> (2) Zusammen- wie auch getrennt geschrieben werden [können …]
>
> - (2.2) Verbindungen mit einem einfachen unflektierten Adjektiv als graduierender Bestimmung […]

Die Nutzung des Bindestrichs ist ein Spezialfall von (1.4).

Nach (2.2) ist die getrennte Schreibweise *mathematisch physikalisch* ebenfalls korrekt, sofern man *mathematisch* als genauere Spezifizierung des primären Adjektivs *physikalisch* betrachtet. Ich persönlich würde den Bindestrich setzen: Betrachtet man die mathematische Physik als Schnittmenge von angewandter Mathematik und theoretischer Physik, ist sie rein formal gesehen einerseits *angewandt mathematisch* und *theoretisch physikalisch*, aber andererseits *mathematisch-physikalisch*.

Wie man sieht, muss hier von Fall zu Fall entschieden werden. Die Schreibweise besitzt keine *allgemeine Gültigkeit*, d. h., sie ist weder *allgemein gültig* noch *allgemeingültig*: Ein *gelbliches Grün* z. B. ist *gelblich grün* oder *gelbgrün*, jedoch **nicht** *gelblich(-)grün* oder *gelb grün*.

Comment: zur genaueren Erörterung dieser Frage wird eine [Reise nach Dresden](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematisch-Physikalischer_Salon) empfohlen ;)

Comment: Wenn es die "mathematische Physik" ist und es um ein Thema der mathematischen Physik geht, so ist es ein "mathematisch physikalisches Thema", ohne Bindestrich. Denn das Thema gehört nur zur Physik, womit nur "physikalisch" ein Adjektiv sein darf. "Mathematisch" ist dann wiederum ein Adverb, dass dann "physikalisch" nochmals genauer beschreibt. Oder? Hast du zu deiner These irgendeinen Beleg oder Erörterung?

Comment: @Em1: Grammatikalische Überlegungen mal außen vor gelassen, mathematisch-physikalisch ist meines Wissens die gängige Schreibweise im universitären Umfeld (z.B. mathematisch-physikalische Seminare/AGs). Man *könnte* dies damit begründen, dass *mathematische Physik* die *physikalische Mathematik* mitumfasst, d.h. es kommt durchaus auch mal vor, dass das Institut für Mathematische Physik dem Fachbereich Mathematik angegliedert ist...

Comment: @Christoph Die mathematische Physik gehört zur angewandten Mathematik. Desderwegen die Angliederung an die Physik. Aber wie du selbst sagst, ist das ja eine nicht-grammatikalische Überlegung.

Comment: @Em1 Richtig. Die Bindestrichschreibweise würde `mathematisch` und `physikalisch` gleichrangig behandeln.